¿Cómo corregir "Type mismatch: inferred type is KFunction3<String, Int, NavOptionsBuilder.() -> Unit, Unit> but (String) -> Unit was expected"?
A partir de Jetpack Compose Navigation 2.8.0-alpha08 es posible pasar objetos para la navegación.
En este caso, yo quiero pasar un objeto que tiene dos propiedades, pero no logro hacer que funcione.
Este es el objeto que sirve como ruta:
@Serializable
data class UniversalisRoute(
    var topicId: String? = null,
    var selectedDate: Int?= Utils.hoy.toInt()
)

Luego en el NavController defino:
fun NavController.navigateToUniversalisFromCalendar(
    topicId: String,
    selectedDate:Int,
    navOptions: NavOptionsBuilder.() -> Unit = {}
) {
    navigate(
        route = UniversalisRoute(topicId,selectedDate)
    )
    {
        navOptions()
    }
}

Y en el NavHost intento poner esto:
calendarScreen(
    onTopicClick = navController::navigateToUniversalisFromCalendar,
)

Entonces obtengo el error:

Type mismatch: inferred type is KFunction3<String, Int,
NavOptionsBuilder.() -> Unit, Unit> but (String) -> Unit was expected

¿Cómo puedo corregir este error?
Yo tengo definida esta ruta, que utilizo en un contexto donde la fecha por defecto es la del día.
fun NavController.navigateToUniversalis(
    topicId: String,
    navOptions: NavOptionsBuilder.() -> Unit = {}
) {
    navigate(
        route = UniversalisRoute(topicId)
    )
    {
        navOptions()
    }
}

Si intento esto:  navController::navigateToUniversalis el código no da error y funciona, pero navega tomando como selectedDate la fecha del día, no la que haya sido pasada desde el evento.
Aquí yo necesito pasar dos parámetros, desde un evento en otra pantalla, y que el ViewModel reciba esos dos parámetros:
    onTopicClick = {
        viewModel::onTopicClick
    }

¿Cómo podría resolver este problema?
